# How to stop event when user clicks inside certain divs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

I want this code to check if the user has clicked inside the open box and if so then it will keep it open, also if the user clicks outside the box it will close.

http://jsfiddle.net/MTJa5/26/

```
var boxes = function(){
    var divClicks = document.getElementsByClassName("clickToShow");
    for(i=0; i < divClicks.length; i++){
        var click = divClicks[i];

        var clickEvent = function(){
            click.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                var currentClass= this.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].className;
                var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('openedBox');
                for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
                    divs[i].setAttribute("class", "closedBox");

                }

                if(currentClass === "openedBox"){
                    this.childNodes[3].setAttribute("class", "closedBox");
                } else {
                    this.childNodes[3].setAttribute("class", "openedBox");

                }
            },false);
        }();
    }
}();
```

Comment: Stopping the event is the wrong philosophy. Ignoring the event is a better idea. You never know what event handler may be relying on that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding several event listeners, you can also bind just one `click` event, and use the `event.target` property to check where you've clicked.

The updated code is less comples, and easier to maintain.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MTJa5/28/

```
 var hellos = function() {
     function closeAllButThisBox(targ) {
         var allBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('openedBox');
         for (var i=allBoxes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
             if (allBoxes[i] !== targ) {
                 allBoxes[i].className = 'closedBox';
             }
         }
     }
     window.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
         var targ = ev.target;
         // Traverse the tree, until you hit the desired / root element
         while (targ && targ !== document.documentElement) {
             if (targ.className.indexOf('openedBox') !== -1) {
                 closeAllButThisBox(targ);
                 // Do nothing when clicking inside an opened box
                 return;
             }
             // This will open boxes, if closed, when clicking at the <p>
             if (targ.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p' && targ.parentNode.className.indexOf('clickToShow') !== -1) {
                 closeAllButThisBox(targ.parentNode);
                 targ.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].className = 'openedBox';
                 return;
             }
             targ = targ.parentNode;
         }
         
         // At this point, the click is not at the right place.
         // Close all boxes by removing the closedBox class names
         var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('openedBox');
         for (var i=boxes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
             boxes[i].className = 'closedBox';
         }
     }, false);
 }();
```

Comment: That works well but I wanted to keep it so that if you have one box open and you open another then the first one closes

Comment: @jamcoupe Your answer does not relate to RobW's. You should store a reference to the last opened box regardless where you implement the event listener.

Comment: @RobW your code works perfectly! Do you have any further readings on the DOM and handeling events you could recommend?

Comment: @PointedEars OP's answer? Did you mean comment? It's a very *good* observation that the last reference should be stored in a reference. *However*, I do not know anything about the rest of OPs code, so I cannot take for granted that all open-div requests are triggered by the click event.

Comment: @RobW In a *variable* or *property* (references are values). But then the other methods should do that in a consistent user interface. Yes, I meant *comment*.

Comment: @jamcoupe A good place to start off is https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/. The MDN is usually a good reference for JavaScript, HTML, CSS and some other technologies.